# DIV is not displaying in IE8 onwards due to CSS class

Tags: html, css, asp.net

When I create a div like below, it is displaying in IE7, but not displaying on IE8 and later versions. When I view source code, I can see this div in all IE versions, but not displaying in IE8 and plus.

My Aspx code:

```
<div runat="server" id="divLoginImage" class="loginImage">
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.loginImage
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -500px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Please note that if I remove class attribute as show below, this is working fine.

```
<div runat="server" id="divLoginImage" >
        </div>
```

What is wrong with my CSS?

Comment: The fact that you're positioning your DIV left:-500px should actually hide it from view. The fact that IE7 is displaying it leads me to believe it doesn't properly support the left position.

Comment: Also what doctype are you using?

Comment: Even I tried with left:0px, + values, still it is not displaying.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Try the HTML5 <!DOCTYPE html> - just for kicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're positioning your DIV left:-500px **should** actually hide it from view.